# pppd (point to point protocol) not working on my custom embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded, ppp

I am using pppd for long time on standard rasbiany(raspberry pi 3b), never face any issue to connect the internet.
But this time i'm using custom linux image for raspberry (generated by yocto) and facing issue to connect the internet as show below logs. UART connection working fine between raspberry and 4g modem.
kindly suggest for the same.
Thanks

```
ATZ
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","portalnmms","",0,0
OK
ATD*99#
CONNECT
Script chat -v -f /etc/ppp/chat/4g.chat finished (pid 6198), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 30
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyAMA0
Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/pap-secrets has world and/or group access
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1c <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0xa8f80db7> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x74 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xcfcfa215> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x74 <auth pap>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1c <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0xa8f80db7> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x75 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xcfcfa215> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x75 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xcfcfa215> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xa8f80db7]
Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/pap-secrets has world and/or group access
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0xa user="raspberrypi3" password=<hidden>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x76 magic=0xcfcfa215]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xcfcfa215 a8 f8 0d b7]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0xa ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0xa <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x77 80 fd 01 0a 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]
Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x1 magic=0xa8f80db7]
IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x1d "No network protocols running"]
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x1e "No network protocols running"]
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```